# Change text color if AA rating more then 4.5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors

I need to know how to change the styling if the AA color rating is more then 4.5.
Lets assume I got this code:

```
<Typography color={textEmphasis}>
            Any text...
</Typography>
```

And I need to change the color if the AA color rating is more then 4,5.
May someone can help me here pls!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is AA color rating?

Comment: AA Color rating depens on the text color and its background. there are plenty of online tools and also in your chrome dev tool, to tell if a text/background contrast pass AA or AAA rating